# How to start a new intent / activity in pure Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I can't seem to find any clear answer about this. Everything else is pretty confusion.

To start a new intent in Kotlin/Android:

```
    val nextScreenIntent = Intent(this, NextScreen::class.java)
    startActivity(nextScreenIntent)
```

Why does it refer to "java" as in class.java?

Isn't there a pure Kotlin to do this?

ADD:

It is not a duplicate question. The other questions/answers do not provide the answer.

What is the pure Kotlin to start an activity or intent, without referencing Java?

Comment: Intent() takes a Class (java) and not a KClass (kotlin), so no

Comment: val intent: Intent = Intent(this@ActivityA,ActivityB::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                
                ///////////or////
                startActivity(Intent(this@ActivityA,ActivityB::class.java))


this is the only way to call the intent in the kotlin and it's intent's feature that it takes the Java class.

Comment: If intent has to take a Java class, then what is the pure Kotlin way to do  it?